# from server check for file on another server

Tags: java

I have two server may be they will be at same network or not,while doing some work in jsp page at server 1 ,I want to check if file exist or not on the second server , How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are determined to do this in java, following is one solution:

1. You need to create a server application on server2 which listens at a port and responds to some requests.
2. You need to create a client application that communicates with the server and get the required information.

Hope this helps!

Comment: my question is to check for file from one server to another server

Comment: check means verify if the file is present or view the contents?

Comment: The server program that is mentioned above can do the same and return a value to the client!

Comment: but there is no client , if i would like to do it from client i can do it easily ,but i have two servers

Comment: Ok, to make it simple. Writing this in Java is a lengthy task and you should be able to use tools like FTP etc. In case you want to develop it in Java, above mentioned solution shall work for you. You need to run the Server Program on the machines where you need to test the file existence.

Comment: @ama. You probably needs to read about basic concepts. Machine 1 might be a server placed in your data room, but that doesn't mean that all software on the machine always are considered as servers in a client-server architecture. Machine 1 needs to know if a file exists on machine 2, so machine 1 will be a client to something that is running on machine 2.